# How do I make an object from another subclass?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, constructor, subclass

So I have a class called `Room` which has the following constructor:

```
public class Room 
{
    public Room(String roomId, String description, double dailyRate)
    {
        this.roomId = roomId;
        this.description = description;
        this.dailyRate = dailyRate;
        this.status = 'A';
    }
}
```

I have sub class called `PremiumRoom` as such:

```
public class PremiumRoom extends Room
{   
    public PremiumRoom(String roomId, String description, double dailyRate, int freeNights, double discountRate, double nextBookingDiscountVoucher)
    {
        super(roomId, description, dailyRate);
        this.freeNights = freeNights;
        this.discountRate = discountRate;
        this.nextBookingDiscountVoucher = nextBookingDiscountVoucher;
    }
}
```

and finally this is where i create the array:

```
public class TestProgram {

    public static final Room[] rooms = new Room[]
        {
            new Room ("GARDEN0001", "NorthWest Garden View", 45.0),
            new Room ("POOL0001", "Poolside Terrace", 90.0),
            new Room ("GARDEN0003", "North Garden View", 35.0),
            new Room ("GARDEN0005", "West Garden View", 35.0),
            new Room ("POOL0002", "Poolside Private", 125.0),
            new Room ("GARDEN0004", "South Garden View", 52.0)
        };
}
```

how do i go about creating an object from the premiumroom sub class? For example, `new Room ("POOL0001", "Poolside Terrace", 90.0)` suppose to be something like `new PremiumRoom ("POOL0001", "Poolside Terrace", 90.0, 1, 150, 50)`, which contains the additional parameters.

How do i do it?

Comment: You are already proposing a solution with correct syntax. What error message do you get when using that syntax?

Comment: You could add a constructor to `PremiumRoom` taking a ` Room` instance as argument, then copying the properties over to itself. If you need to simply add a ` PremiumRoom` to the array, declare it as type `Room` and initialize as `PremiumRoom`.

Comment: it gives me an error saying "PremiumRoom cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: You probably didn't not import the package in PremiumRoom class

Comment: Is `TestProgram` in a different package than `PremiumRoom `?

Comment: @underdog , you are right. silly me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a PremiumRoom like this:

```
Room premium = new PremiumRoom ("POOL0001", "Poolside Terrace", 90.0, 1, 150, 50);
```

You will be able to insert it to the array...

When you retrieve the rooms you must use [`instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) to determine which class of `Room` is and then cast to `PremiumRoom`

Comment: I tried it before, it gives me an error saying "PremiumRoom cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: i did not import the premiumroom class. :D hahahahahaha